# array_keys returning higher number than end($array)

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file that contains around 8500 lines but I'm getting a really weird "bug".

I'm validating the data inside the CSV to make sure the data is cool to import into the database. I currently just log the data errors to a log file, but when I open it I see error reports for rows upto 8800 (give or take).

I did some basic debugging to see what's what and did this to begin with:

```
foreach ($csv as $key => $row)
{
    if ($key > 8500) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

and that only returned about 50/60 more which is fine as the total rows is around that number.

I then tried doing this to get the end array result:

```
$last = end($csv);
print_r($last);
```

and that showed an array with data as expected. However when I do this:

```
var_dump(array_keys($csv));
```

then it shows 8800 (give or take) values. Doing `count($csv)` returns the same number.

I've tried going into the actual CSV and highlighting everything below the last row and hitting clear but it still has the same affect..
Here's how I build my `$csv` array:

```
$skus = $csv = [];

if (($handle = fopen($fileTmp, 'r')) !== false) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $i = 0;

    while (($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false)
    {
        $colCount = count($csvData);

        $csv[$i]['sku'] = $csvData[0];
        $csv[$i]['desc'] = $csvData[1];
        $csv[$i]['ean'] = $csvData[2];
        $csv[$i]['rrp_less_vat'] = $csvData[3];
        $csv[$i]['rrp_inc_vat'] = $csvData[4];
        $csv[$i]['stock'] = $csvData[5];
        $csv[$i]['est_delivery'] = $csvData[6];
        $csv[$i]['img_name'] = $csvData[7];
        $csv[$i]['vatable'] = $csvData[8];
        $csv[$i]['obsolete'] = $csvData[9];
        $csv[$i]['dead'] = $csvData[10];
        $csv[$i]['replacement_product'] = $csvData[11];
        $csv[$i]['brand'] = $csvData[12];
        $csv[$i]['ext_desc'] = $csvData[13];

        $i++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that I can't see in building the array or is this unexpected behaviour?

> PHP version: 7.1 
>   OS: Linux Mint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have lines that are longer than the `$length` argument you are passing to `fgetcsv()`. From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), emphasis mine:

> Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). **Otherwise the line is split in chunks of `length` characters**, unless the split would occur inside an enclosure.

The easiest fix is to stop limiting the length of the line to 1000:

```
while (($csvData = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
```

Comment: will accept when I can :) is it worth using `trim` on the data before appending to array to try and avoid the trailing chars?

Comment: The trailing empty elements occur because some lines are being split into multiple pieces. If you remove the limitation (the `1000`), that should no longer occur (assuming that all of the 'cells' in your CSV contain data).

Comment: I see weird, never seen this in my usage of `fgetcsv` before! Learn something new everyday :) ty :)